# How can you convert quarterly data into monthly data in R?

Tags: r, data-conversion

I am currently trying to convert quarterly GDP data into monthly data and make it a time series. I figured out a way to do so before, however, I lost my code for it and cannot figure it out again. My data needs to span from 1997-01-01 to 2018-12-01, and the original data I had taken from the Fred database.

```
library(pdfetch)
GDP.1 <- pdfetch_FRED("GDP")
```

My code looked something like this...

```
GDP.working <- seq(as.Date(GDP.1, "1997/1/1"),
                    by = "month",
                    length.out = 252)

xts.1 <- xts(x = rep(NA,252),
            order.by = seq(as.Date("1997/1/1"), 
                           by = "month", 
                           length.out = 252),
            frequency = 12)

xts.GDP.1 <- merge(GDP.working, xts.1)

GDP.final <- na.locf(xts.GDP.1, fromLast = TRUE)
```

Any suggestions/methods would be very much appreciated. 
Thank you for your time.
ERV

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you're open to using libraries, I commonly find `lubridate`'s and `zoo`'s date/time functions very helpful.  I don't know any ones dealing with quarters off hand but I think it's likely there's a function just for your need.

Comment: Could you give some dataset using dput()?

Comment: Here are parts of the code, the whole was too long to post.  ```structure(c(243.164, 245.968, 249.585, 259.745, 265.742, 272.567, 
279.196, 280.366, 275.034, 271.351, 272.889, 270.627, 280.828, 
290.383, 308.153, 319.945, 336, 344.09, 351.385, 356.178, 359.82, 
361.03, 367.701, 380.812, 387.98, 391.749, 391.171, 385.97, 385.345, ```

Comment: ``` 1435622400, 1443571200, 1451520000, 1459382400, 1467244800, 1475193600, 
1483142400, 1490918400, 1498780800, 1506729600, 1514678400, 1522454400, 
1530316800, 1538265600, 1546214400, 1553990400, 1561852800, 1569801600
), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "GDP")) ```

Comment: please use dput(head(your_dataframe, 10)) to get only the first 10 rows and then paste here

Comment: ```structure(c(243.164, 245.968, 249.585, 259.745, 265.742, 272.567, 
279.196, 280.366, 275.034, 271.351), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(-718156800, 
-710294400, -702345600, -694396800, -686534400, -678672000, -670723200, 
-662774400, -654998400, -647136000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "GDP"))
>```